# envoy Команда не найдена

Tags: laravel, ubuntu

Подскажите пожалуйста , ошибка envoy Команда не найдена

Выполнял команду `PATH="$(composer config -g home)/vendor/bin:$PATH"`, перелогинился, но ошибка та же

Вот что выдает команда **echo $PATH** - `/home/mavrin/.config/composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`

Ubuntu 20.04 что делать ?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, все из за того что папка была на рабочем столе